# Link with href to id on page not including route data

Tags: html, asp.net-core, hyperlink

Generating documentation in an ASP.NET Core MVC app. The view renders headings with ids and the contents of other sections needs to link to them.

Example view:

```
@foreach (MyObject thing in Model)
{
    <h5 id="@thing.Name">@thing.Name</h5>

    <h6>List</h6>
    @foreach (MySubObject otherThing in thing.SubObjects)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">@otherThing.Name</div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                @if (otherThing.HasParent)
                {
                    <a href="@($"#{otherThing.ParentName}")">
                        @otherThing.ParentName
                    </a>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

This generates exactly what I want it to:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">OtherThing7Name</div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#ParentName">
                    ParentName
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <h5 id="ParentName">ParentName</h5>
```

But the link, when I hover over it, goes to http://localhost/#ParentName instead of preserving the route data e.g. http://localhost/Documentation/Things#ParentName, so instead of just jumping to that location on the page, it takes it to the root of the application.

Update:

Okay, it looks like this is happening because `<base href="~/" />` is defined in the View Layout being used (which all Views in the application use). Removing it allowed the link to work as expected, but I don't know what effects it would have on the rest of the site.

Comment: Just a guess, but you may want to try "/#ParentName", or "./#ParentName".